# MYSQL: Filter out based on count on another table?

Tags: mysql

I have a quick form where I have a weekly event allowing people to sign up for a timeslot however I want to limit to 3 people signing up for a particular timeslot every week

I have 2 tables (3 if you count the user/userid table)

timeslots:

```
+  id  +  slot  +  enabled  +
+------+--------+-----------+
+   1  + 12:00  +     1     +
+------+--------+-----------+
+   2  + 12:03  +     1     +
+------+--------+-----------+
+   3  + 12:06  +     1     +
+------+--------+-----------+
+   4  + 12:09  +     0     +
+------+--------+-----------+
```

signups:

```
+  userid  +  date       +  timeslotid  +
+----------+-------------+--------------+
+   133    + 2020-12-01  +     2        +
+----------+-------------+--------------+
+   167    + 2020-12-01  +     2        +
+----------+-------------+--------------+
+   356    + 2020-12-01  +     2        +
+----------+-------------+--------------+
```

I want to see a list of all enabled timeslot ids and slots that are available that do not have 3 people signed up for 12/01/2020

So in the example above I'd expect to see

```
+  id  +  slot  +
+------+--------+
+   1  + 12:00  +
+------+--------+
+   3  + 12:06  +
+------+--------+
```

If you asked me to do this 10 years ago I think I could have it handed back in 15 minutes however I'm completely drawing a blank.

I've started a join query that joins the two tables based on timeslots.id and signups.timeslotid.  Trying to figure out how to filter where count(signups.timeslotid) < 3 and date = 2020-12-01

**SOLVED:**

After direction from ImCrimson this seems to have done the trick.

```
SELECT t.id, t.slot FROM timeslots t LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM signup WHERE date = '2020-12-01') s ON (t.id = s.timeslotId) WHERE t.enabled = 1 GROUP BY t.id, t.slot HAVING (COUNT(*) < 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the HAVING clause

```
SELECT statements... GROUP BY column_name1[,column_name2,...] [HAVING condition]
```

Comment: See my update above.  This did the trick and did exactly what I was looking for.